# Problem with Accessing the Flask local application

Tags: python, flask

I just recently came to know abt the module flask for creating website using python and After learning abt it i just made a project of my own. Initially while i tried running this project everything was good i was able to access the local application created in the localhost:5000 by the flask module, but recently when i tried running the same project i wasn't able to access localost:5000. I didn't change anything in the code and i tried re-running the code and restarting chrome multiple times but still i wasn't able to fix the problem.
It would be really helpful if y'all say a good fix to the above mentioned problem.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend some points that usually work for me while reviving some old flask projects.

- I usually run Flask applications with `pipenv`. Check if you have been using it. If it was on pipenv, `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` files must be present. In that case, jump to the virtual environment and try running the application there.
- Check whether local variables like `FLASK_APP` and `FLASK_ENV` are set or whether they conflict with the running of the application.
- Check for updates and if the code is compatible with the version of Flask.
- Try checking for other services running on the localhost:5000. If it is, try running the Flask application on some other port.
- Check for internal conflicts with the Flask application. This may happen due to outdated dependencies.
- Lastly, try updating the system and modules. Check for any outdated third-party modules used in the application and try updating them.

It would have been more helpful if you would have provided the error. These are some general debugging that I hope will get your application running.